# Web socket fails on iOS

Tags: ios, websocket

My code attempts to create a websocket connection.

It works on Windows, Mac and Ubuntu and on Safari, Firefox, Chrome and Edge.

It does not work on iOS (iPhone and iPad) and I have tested this failure on Safari and Chrome only. I guess it may not work for other browsers on iOS too.

I get the following error on iPad:

> error: Websocket connection to 'wss://XXXX' failed: The operation could not be completed. (kNWErrorDomainPOSIX error 14 - Bad address).

On iPhone it gives a slightly different error:

> error: Websocket connection to 'wss://XXXX' failed: The operation could not be completed. kNWErrorDomainPOSIX error 100 - Protocol error.

Where XXXX is a valid network address (domain name / remote IP / local network IP).

Answer (score 1):

Try entering a servers local ip address http://192.168.xx.xx:PORT and make sure both devices are on same local network

Comment: Is the "http" in your reply intentional? Coz for websockets it has to be ws or wss. Also I tried giving wss://192.168.xx.xx:PORT and same error. Maybe my earlier question was not too clear - I was indeed using the above format for the URL - have edited it to avoid confusion.

Comment: yes try http it may work

Comment: No, http does not work for web sockets.